# Proving that $\gamma$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

I want to show that an Ellipse $E$ is homeomorphic to the unit sphere $S^1$.

I believe that $$\gamma : E\to S^1, (x,y)\mapsto \left(\frac{1}{a}x,\frac{1}{b}y\right)$$ is the homeomoprhism.

To prove that $\gamma$ actually is a homeomorphism, I have to show that $\gamma$ is bijective, continuous and $\gamma^{-1}$ is continuous.

**Bijective**

I believe it suffices to explicitly construct the inverse.

The inverse of $\gamma$ is $\gamma^{-1}: S^{1}\to E, (x,y)\mapsto (ax,by)$.

$\gamma \circ \gamma^{-1} =\operatorname{id}_{S^1}$ and $\gamma ^{-1}\circ \gamma = \operatorname{id}_{E}$.

**Continuity**

$\gamma$ is continuous if $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ is continuous. This is true since both component functions are polynomials.

Likewise, $\gamma^{-1}$ is continuous as a polyonomial.

Does that prove that $E$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$?

Comment: Once you know $\gamma$ is a continuous bijection you’re done as such a map between compact metric spaces is always a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given the description of the ellipse. I assume it is $$E = \left\{(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 : \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^2 = 1\right\}.$$
In this case, your proof is correct. You are correct that it suffices to construct an inverse. In this case, the maps you've defined are easily seen to be inverses of each other. One small check that you must do is note that the maps you've defined actually do have the correct codomain (which is quite straightforward here).

Comment: Thanks, yes, your assumption is correct - what do you mean by checking the codomain? That it is well-defined?

Comment: @Analysis: Essentially that, yes. Basically that $\gamma(x, y) \in S^1$ for all $(x, y) \in E$.

Comment: Well, this is really obvious, but how do I prove it formally?

Comment: @Analysis: Well, you only need to stare at it a bit and realise. Indeed, you have $\gamma(x, y) = (x/a, y/b)$. For it to be in $S^1$, you must have $(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 = 1$. But that is precisely the condition it satisfies because it is in $E$.